# Number has no neighboring numbers in regex

Tags: regex

I would like to get regex to find a specific number. As an example

These should be true

```
99 Hello
Hello 99 Hello
Hello 99
(99 Hello)
99 Hello 999
```

While this should be false

```
999 Hello
```

As you can see, I want to find any occurrence of the number 99 but want to ensure that it has no neighboring numbers. This seems like it should be easy but I haven't found anything that has completely satisfied my requirements.

Edit:
I have tried several different suggestions that I've found on stackoverflow. Unfortunately, I didn't keep track on them. I'll see if I can find them again after a meeting I need to go to and post here. Mostly I am experiementing with something along the lines of `[?0-9]` before and after 99 in order to ensure that the neighbors of the number I need are not numbers. Unfortunately, that method fails if `99` is at the beginning or or end of a line.

I've tried these and they fail the tests
    [?0-9]{0,1}99[?0-9]{0,1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex101 is good for this type of thing.

\b99\b would do the trick. \b is whitespace, linestart, or lineend.

Comment: You don't need the same character twice in a character set

Comment: Sure, I could do [9]{1,2} - OP was explicitly calling out 99 though

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I couldn't find anything that met all the conditions. I touched on `\b` but the regex I made missed the mark

Comment: `[9]{1,2}` matches both 9 and 99.

Comment: Wow, that is so simple it's embarrassing. Thanks again